# Why EF doesn't support merge to object graphs feature?

Tags: entity-framework

Why EF doesn't support merge to object graphs feature.

I think it would be good in some scenarios use merge to object grhaps function.

For example merge detached from ObjectContext graph with graph received from database(attached to ObjectContext).

For detecting modified on another tier objects in object graph.

Answer (score 1):

Simply it doesn't. Only EF development team can answer such question so either contact them through their [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/contact.aspx) or propose this as a feature on [Data UserVoice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions).

My opinion: I answered few questions about merging detached object graphs to an existing object graph and it is quite complex problem where every scenario has some new requirements. Because of that I think it is too complex and too dangerous to be automated. Dangerous because in many cases such automerge can impose new security vulnerabilities by modifying not only relations in object graph but also related entities which were not supposed to be modified. To support all scenarios the feature will have to be quite complicated (support a lot of configuration how the merge should be done) and at the end the effort and cost of this feature would not worth its value because most programers want to persist detached changes without loading the entity graph again = without object level merge.